# AJAX and post data : forms

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to post some data with AJAX. I'm sending a serialized form, but nothing is sent. What can go wrong ? How can I fix it?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'postcreaorganisation',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        //success action
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions){
        //error action
    }  
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit : I should specify that I use that code in a dialog confirm button's action.

Comment: is that your url? postcreaorganisation?

Comment: Yep. Nothing wrong here (it's a controller). And I checked, the controller receives the post, for that matter.

Comment: Your form's id is `form`? And you are sure that the (**relative**) url is correct?

Comment: So the AJAX request is sent, just minus the form data? Have you tried using `$('#form').serialize();` instead?

Comment: @GabrielTheron and the controller handles the request correctly? What is the exact data that you get back?

Comment: Both URL and id are correct. Only a post request is sent. I'll try `serialize();` and tell you what I get. The controller, for the moment, simply prints the data it receives, which is `Array` or `array (0) {}` (if I encode with JSON)

Comment: The content of the post is always empty, both with `serialize()` and `serializeArray()`. It's my controller that prints Array or array (0) {}.

Comment: use firebug in mozilla or use developer tools in google chrome; analyze network status, and check there if any error.

Comment: I used Firebug to see the content of the POST. It's empty, but there is no network error of any kind. Everything works fine, except it doesn't seem to find the form/"believes" it's empty

Comment: Try to `console.log($('#form').serializeArray())`.  Make sure there's something there.  Do all your form fields have `name` attributes?

Comment: With name it works. I generated ids instead of name :/ It works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your form elements have `name` attributes.  jQuery's `.serialize` only works with form elements that have `name`s.